# R: how to declare a vector of models

Tags: r

With train data X (dimension `n*L`), and Label data Y (dimension `n*L`), I need to train a linear model on each dimension Y. like:

```
for(l in 1:L){
    models[l] = fit(X, Y[,l])
}
```

Then how can declare the variable `model` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `list` object, but then you need to access the individual models with double-brackets.

```r
models <- list()

for(l in 1:L){
    models[[l]] = fit(X, Y[,l])
} 

summary(models[[1]])
```